# AOP with Spring and the X-Ray SDK for Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-xray

I am trying to trace a request in spring boot application. I am running `AWS X-Ray` Daemon locally which is listing on UDP port 2000 but it is not sending the trace data to the AWS `X-Ray`. My application is a standalone application which does some processing and is not a web-based application so I can't use the `X-Ray` servlet filter to trace request. Anyone knows the how trace request in non-web based spring boot application with `AWS XRay`?

Answer (score 0):

There are various of public APIs for creating segment manually: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray-sdk-for-java/latest/javadoc/.

By default the X-Ray recorder uses `ThreadLocal` to store the created segments so anywhere in the same thread you can easily access the segment and add data to it. You can wrap the entire work done by a segment (which is equivalent to a X-Ray servlet filter would do for a web app request/response cycle) and then create subsegments for subtasks as usual.